# how to change csv headers irrespective of there positions

Tags: php, csv

how to change csv headers irrespective of there positions . for example 
My csv file is :

```
category  Heat  value
25        25c   100
36        36c   256
```

I need to convert it to

```
heat_value  Value   categories
25c         100      25
36c         256      36
```

please help me out how to change the csv file in this format and need to save it.

```
$csvpath = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['csvfile']['name']; 
if(isset($csvpath)) { 
     $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvpath)); 
     echo "<pre>"; 
     array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) { 
         $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a); }); 
     $data = $csv;
}
```

second part

```
$columnHeadings["category"] = "categories";
$columnHeadings["Heat"] = "heat_value"; 
$columnHeadings["value"] = "Value";
foreach($data[0] as $key => $value) { 
    if ($columnHeadings[$key]) { 
         $fields[] = $columnHeadings[$key]; 
    } 
    else { 
         $fields[] = $key; 
    } 
} 
print_r($fields);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us some code and don't just expect us to write code for you.

Comment: $csvpath = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['csvfile']['name'];  
 
 if(isset($csvpath))
 {
  $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvpath));
  echo "<pre>"; 
     array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) 
     { 
      $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a); 
     });  

    $data = $csv;

Comment: part 2 
$columnHeadings["category"] = "categories";
$columnHeadings["Heat"] = "heat_value";
$columnHeadings["value"] = "Value";
foreach($data[0] as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($columnHeadings[$key])
        {
          $fields[] = $columnHeadings[$key]; 
        }
        else
        {
          $fields[] = $key;
        } 
    } 

    print_r($fields);



I can convert the headers using this but i am not getting the rows

Comment: please don't add code in comments, just add it to your question. with the right formatting, please ^^

Comment: do I understand correctly, you only want to change the column name but not the order of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just edit the first line after reading in your csv file into the array (the `$rename` line and the `foreach` loop):

```
if(isset($csvpath)) { 
     $rename = array('category'=>'categories', 'Heat'=>'heat_value'); 
     $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvpath)); 
     foreach($csv[0] as $col => $colname) {
         if(!empty($rename[$colname])) $csv[0][$col] = $rename[$colname];
     }
     array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) { 
         $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a); }); 
     $data = $csv;
}
```

now you wouldn't even need your second part of code to change it after you already read it.

Comment: sure i will do that

Answer (score 0):

Write simple, may be have some error.

```
$file = fopen('xxx.csv','r'); 
$saveData = [];
$isFirst = true;
// oldKey => newName
$order = [1=>'heat_value', 2=> 'Value', 0=> 'categories'];
while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $newRow = [];
    foreach($order as $oldKey => $newName)
        if($isFirst) {
           $row[$oldKey] = $newName;
        }
        $newRow[] = $row[$oldKey];
    }
    $isFirst = false;
    $saveData[] = $newRow;
}
$file.close();
//open file and save csv
$file = fopen('xxx.csv','w'); 
//fputcsv. I forget how to use it...
$file.close();
```

> **fputcsv** usage you can look document [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: `$isFirst = false;` must be set after the inner `foreach`

Comment: um, your edit made it worse... the `= true` was at the right place, the `= false` must go outside and after the inner foreach

Comment: @jakumi :   here my order of column may change with respect to csv file.
I have to replace the column name .. for example : category should change to categories irrespective of order

Comment: @user6527 it will change, yes. the code is not mine though ;o)